# By using java script how can i pass values from one html page to another html page?

Tags: javascript, html

Passing of values from one html page to another html page using javascript
And below is my code:
Fisrt page as html1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <script>
       function newDoc() 
       {
       window.location.assign("html2.html");
       }
    </script>
   </head>
      <body>
         <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="newDoc ()">
      </body>
  </html>
```

And the second html code as html2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script>
        function newDoc()
        {
         window.location.assign("html1.html");
        }
      </script>
     </head>
      <body>
         <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="newDoc ()">
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to store values in [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Use some cookies?

Comment: Why not simply use POST or GET?

Comment: read docs. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 2):

In html we can load other files into one html file using Iframe

```
    <body>

      <iframe src="html2.html">

      </iframe>

   </body>
```

We can use jquery function to load the file into some specific div.

```
     <script> 
       $(function(){
        $('#header').load("header2.html"); 
       });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, `window.location` object has a `search` attribute. So, if your location is `http://example.com/html1.html?foo=bar` then your `window.location.search` is `?foo=bar` (`console.log(window.location)`).

How to parse `search` string: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If the variable that you want to pass is important for your application, maybe it will be better to store it in localStorage/sessionStorage or a cookie.